# Checkmarks disappearing when scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

As the title says, my checkmarks are disappearing. The answers I've found just post fixes for the specific code, so I'm not sure what's wrong with mine.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cellx: UITableViewCell = self.tableViewOut.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellx", forIndexPath: indexPath)



    // Configure the cell...

    switch (indexPath.section) {


    case 0:
        cellx.textLabel?.text = "\(qUnitArray[indexPath.row])\t\t\t\(functionList.searchUnitCount(ttopicArray, funitSearch: qUnitArray[indexPath.row])) \t \(functionList.searchUnitRating(ttopicArray, fDataStore: tDataStore, funitRating: qUnitArray[indexPath.row]))"
        cellx.accessoryType = .None
        conUnit = qUnitArray[indexPath.row]

        conUnitCount = 0
        while conUnitCount < selectedUnit.count {
            if selectedUnit[conUnitCount] == qUnitArray[indexPath.row] {
                cellx.accessoryType = .Checkmark
                print("checkmark change")
            }
            conUnitCount += 1 
        }
    case 1:
        cellx.textLabel?.text = "\(qsubjectArray[indexPath.row])\t\t\t\(functionList.searchSubjectCount(ttopicArray, fsubjectSearch: qsubjectArray[indexPath.row])) \t \(functionList.searchSubjectRating(ttopicArray, fDataStore: tDataStore, fsubjectRating: qsubjectArray[indexPath.row]))"
        cellx.accessoryType = .None
        conSubject = qsubjectArray[indexPath.row]

        conSubjectCount = 0
        while conSubjectCount < selectedSubject.count {
            if selectedSubject[conSubjectCount] == qsubjectArray[indexPath.row] {
                cellx.accessoryType = .Checkmark
                print("checkmark change")

            }
            conSubjectCount += 1
        }
    default:
        cellx.textLabel?.text = "Other"

    }






func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cellx = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        if cellx.accessoryType == .Checkmark
        {
            cellx.accessoryType = .None

            if indexPath.section == 0 {
                while tempUnitCount < tselectedArray[0].count {
                    if qUnitArray[indexPath.row] == tselectedArray[0][tempUnitCount] {
                        tempUnitCode = tempUnitCount
                    }
                    tempUnitCount += 1 
                }
                tselectedArray[0].removeAtIndex(tempUnitCode)
                tempUnitCode = 0
                tempUnitCount = 0
            } else {
                while tempSubjectCount < tselectedArray[1].count {
                    if qsubjectArray[indexPath.row] == tselectedArray[1][tempSubjectCount] {
                        tempSubjectCode = tempSubjectCount
                    }
                    tempSubjectCount += 1 
                }

                tselectedArray[1].removeAtIndex(tempSubjectCode)
                tempSubjectCode = 0
                tempSubjectCount = 0
            }
        }
        else {
            cellx.accessoryType = .Checkmark

            if indexPath.section == 0 {
                if tselectedArray[0] == [""] {
                    tselectedArray[0][0] = qUnitArray[indexPath.row]
                } else {
                    tselectedArray[0].append(qUnitArray[indexPath.row])
                }
            }else {
                if tselectedArray[1] == [""] {
                    tselectedArray[1][0] = qsubjectArray[indexPath.row]
                } else {
                    tselectedArray[1].append(qsubjectArray[indexPath.row])
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't set the accessoryType in this method.  Don't alter the cell in any way here.

Cells are gotten on demand from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and cells of the same type are reused. So, change something in the datasource so that it knows the new state and call one of the tableView reloading functions to get it to remake the cell.

When your cell scrolls off and then back on, it will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` -- the cell you are changing is not a permanent change to the table.

Comment: Brilliant, I get it entirely! One issue, how do I go about reloading the table view.

Comment: do I just bung self.tableView.reloadData() into the function

Comment: So, while I understand what you meant, I have  failed to put it into practice! I've added the cell for row at index path bit. Any chance you could spot where I'm going wrong

Comment: You aren't showing the whole function, so this is a guess. When you dequeue a cell at the top of cellForRow... it could be one that has scrolled off (they are reused). So, you must set the accessory in all paths of the function or it will have its old value. Assume the cell has random data in it and reset everything you have ever set to some value.

Comment: There are many ways to reload. reloadData reloads every cell -- so you call this if you don't really know what has changed.  If you know one specific cell has changed (and there are no insertions, deletions, or other changes), call 
`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` -- there are other functions to call if you know that you inserted or deleted rows.  You could also batch a sequence of updates (delete some, insert some, reload some, etc)